# Spring AMQP return callback vs retry callback

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I want to make my app resilient to connection issues that can happen when sending messages to rabbitmq. I want to get hold of all unsent messages, store them and send them latter, when rabbitmq becomes available.

Looking at the official [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#template-confirms) I didn't manage to figure out what is the difference between return callback and retry callback. I understand that retry callback is invoked when retry template exhausts configured policy but don't find this much useful since context doesn't contain message itself. 
Based on "replyCode" that is passed in the "returnedMessage" method of ReturnCallback interface one can easily determine further behavior but haven't figured out when this callback is invoked.

One way to go is ConfirmCallback but there is an issue of having additional logic for keeping in sync CorrelationData and messages and statuses of those messages.

So...except ConfirmCallback interface is there any easier way to keep track of messages that are not successfully sent through RabbitMQ using Spring AMQP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returns are when the broker returns a message because it's undeliverable (no matching bindings on the exchange to which the message was published, and the mandatory bit is set).

Confirms are when the broker sends an ack back to the publisher, indicating that a message was successfully routed.

Retry is outside the broker realm so it is likely what you need for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. If "Retry" is the way to go, is there any example how to obtain the message itself, since all I get is the policy itself inside the context map? In mentioned document one can extract message itself but didn't find it was the case in my code.

Comment: As discussed in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#template-retry) the message is not made available as a value in the `RetryContext` by default, but you can do by using an external `RetryTemplate` instead of one configured inside the `RabbitTemplate`. I think we should go ahead and make the message available under a well-known key in the context. Please open an ['improvement' JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) and we'll take a look, but an external retry template should work for you.