# Spring AMQP : [RabbitTemplate] Hystrix fallback is not getting invoked when RabbitTemplate ReturnCallback is executed

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp, hystrix

I am using hystrix to handle falback scenarios when my messages are not delivered to RabbitMQ server. My fallback is getting invoked when RabbitMQ server is down(as AMQPException is thrown). 
If broker is unable to accept/route the messages then returnCallback/returnConfirm(with nack) is invoked.
What I understand is that RabbitTemplate returnCallbacks/returnConfirms will be executed in different thread than the Hystrix thread.

Is it possible to throw Exception in these scenarios so that Hystrix fallback gets executed?

I have referred these q's : [Spring AMQP return callback vs retry callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034092/spring-amqp-return-callback-vs-retry-callback)

[Spring RabbitTemplate- How to get hold of the published message for NACKs in Publisher confirm mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125116/spring-rabbittemplate-how-to-get-hold-of-the-published-message-for-nacks-in-pub)

Any pointer to handle this scenario is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; returns are completely asynchronous; even if you enable transactions - from [the rabbit mq documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html)...

> AMQP does not specify when errors (e.g. lack of permissions, references to unknown exchanges) in transactional basic.publish and basic.ack commands should be detected. RabbitMQ performs the necessary checks immediately (rather than, say, at the time of commit), but note that both basic.publish and basic.ack are asynchronous commands so any errors will be reported back to the client asynchronously.

If you publish to a non-existent exchange (and `setChannelTransacted(true)`*) you will get an exception on the commit, but publishing to an exchange with no routable queue will never get an exception (only an async return callback).

- enabling transactions is quite expensive for all operations so consider it carefully if you want to catch this particular scenario

Comment: This information is really helpful. Thanks for this valuable information.